# sed - replace a variable of power 2 by the product of two variables

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to replace with `sed` the following expression :

```
cos(2*a)^2+sin(3*b)^2+m1^2*m2^2*cos(4*c)
```

by

```
cos(2*a)*cos(2*a)+sin(3*b)*sin(3*b)+m1*m1*m2*m2*cos(4*c)
```

As you can see, I would like to convert all variables with power 2 (with ^2 exposant) by the product of these variables by themselves.

I tried to do it with pattern preceding the symbol "^2":

```
echo "cos(2*a)^2+sin(3*b)^2+m1^2*m2^2*cos(4*c)"  | sed 's/\(.*\)\^2/\1\*\1/g'
```

but it does not work.

If someone could help me ...

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a simple task. How do you determine what the "unit" before the `^2` is? You need to parse the expression and `sed` can't do that.

Comment: Regular expressions are not the solution to every problem. In general, the set of valid mathematical expressions do not constitute a regular language, due to the ability to have arbitrarily nested subexpressions inside parentheses. `sed` regular expressions are unable to recognize such strings correctly. For example, you cannot write a regular expression that correctly identifies correctly matched parentheses. If you can give a *precise* definition of what is allowed before `^`, you *may* be able to write a regular expression to capture it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with character classes:

```
sed 's/\([^(*+\/^-]*\(([^)]*)\)\?\)\^2/\1\*\1/g'
```

Note that this will stop to work if you have nested parenthesis.

Comment: thank you very much, now I am going to try to understand this magic command line

Comment: @user1773603: There is nothing magic, it is very simple: `[^(+/^-]` is a character class that excludes `(`, `+`, `^`, `-` *(so a character that is not in this list)*. `\(([^)]*)\)` is a group that describes something enclosing between parenthesis and `\?` makes it optional.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte what have I to add if I have nested parenthesis like into the expression : (l3^2*m3*(m1*m2 + m1*m3 + 2*m2*m3 - m2^2*cos(t1 - t2)^2 - m3^2*cos(t1 - t3)^2 - m3^2*cos(t2 - t3)^2 + m2^2 + m3^2 - m1*m3*cos(t2 - t3)^2 - m2*m3*cos(t1 - t3)^2 -
m2*m3*cos(t2 - t3)^2 + 2*m2*m3*cos(t1 - t2)*cos(t1 - t3)*cos(t2 - t3)))

Comment: @user37422: in this case sed is no more the right tool. Perl will be better fitted for this task because it's possible to build recursive patterns, but even with Perl, you can't do it in one pass (except if you use a dynamic replacement)