# sed - replace a variable of power N by the product of N variables

Tags: regex, bash, sed

from [sed replace a variable of power by the product of two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357988/sed-replace-a-variable-of-power-2-by-the-product-of-two-variables), I would like to generalize the "power 2" case to "N power case".

The command line in the "power 2" case is :

```
sed 's/\([^(*+\/^-]*\(([^)]*)\)\?\)\^2/\1\*\1/g'
```

So that

```
cos(2*a)^2+sin(3*b)^2+m1^2*m2^2*cos(4*c)
```

is replaced by :

```
cos(2*a)*cos(2*a)+sin(3*b)*sin(3*b)+m1*m1*m2*m2*cos(4*c)
```

Now, I want to transform :

```
cos(a)^3 +m1^4
```

to

```
cos(a)*cos(a)*cos(a)+m1*m1*m1*m1
```

Is there a way to store the exponent "N" and print N times the variable powered `with star symbol` ?

It would be something like this (we store the exponent in pattern `\2`) :

```
sed 's/\([^(*+\/^-]*\(([^)]*)\)\?\)\^\([0-9]*\)/
```

"print N times (`pattern \2`) factors `\1`"

```
  \1\*\1*\1*\1 /g'
```

If somenone has a solution with other tools (other Linux commands), I take.

Comment: This is not the craziest thing I've seen people attempt to do with `sed`, but it is quite crazy. Are you sure you want to do this with `sed`? This sort of thing would be much easier with a programming language that supports basic arithmetic.

Comment: The first problem is that you must clearly define the *scope* of the power. What are the rules to determine *which* part to repeat. Furthermore please note that a language which brackets cannot be parsed by a *strict* regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "cos(a)^3 +m1^4" | sed '
# encapsulate between +
s/.*/+&+/
:a
# For each power object
/\^/!b end

# isolate power object
h
s#\(.*[-+/*^]\)\([^-+/*^]*\)^\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)\(.*\)#\1\
\2\
\4#

# isolate power value to convert it in useable reproducing factor
x
s//00\3/
s/\(.\)\{0,1\}\(.\)\{0,1\}\(.\)\{0,1\}/\1C\2D\3/
s/0.//g;s/9/18/g;s/8/17/g;s/7/16/g;s/6/15/g;s/5/14/g;s/4/13/g;s/3/12/g;s/2/11/g;s/1/U/g
:cdu
s/1\(1*\)\([^1]\)/\2\1\2/g;t cdu
s/C/DDDDDDDDDD/g;s/D/UUUUUUUUUU/g
# dont replicate power 1
s/U//
# we got the replication number

# replicate
G
:repl
s/^U\(U*\n.*\n\)\(.*\)\(\n\)\(.*\)/\1\2\3*\2\4/;t repl

# reassemble
s/\n//g
b a

:end
# remove extra +
s/.\(.*\)./\1/
'
```

Let's be crazy in this mad world (I don't recommend this in production, especially for maintenance and modification)

- Limited to power: positive, integer and smaller than 999
- Some comment in code but not exhaustive (a bit long)
- Tested on GNU sed but POSIX compliant
- Recursive process so nearly any simple powered argument between `+-*/^` should work up to the limit of sed itself.

Answer (score 3):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  RS = "[ \n+]"
  FS = "^"
  OFS = "*"
}
{
  z = $2
  for (y=2; y<=z; y++)
    $y = $1
  printf "%s%s", $0, RT
}
```

Input

```
sin(b)
cos(a)^3 +m1^4
tan(c)
```

Output

```
sin(b)
cos(a)*cos(a)*cos(a) +m1*m1*m1*m1
tan(c)
```